# lighttpd cannot be started on centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, lighttpd

on centos 7 system, when i tried to start the lighttpd it show: **[OK]** . However when i check it with service lighttpd status, it show following log:

```
[root@km15501 lighttpd]# service lighttpd status
● lighttpd.service - Lightning Fast Webserver With Light System Requirements
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2016-03-15 02:19:11 CET; 6s ago
  Process: 8583 ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 8583 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

Mar 15 02:19:11 km15501.servernode.de systemd[1]: Started Lightning Fast Webserver With Light System Requirements.
Mar 15 02:19:11 km15501.servernode.de systemd[1]: Starting Lightning Fast Webserver With Light System Requirements...
Mar 15 02:19:11 km15501.servernode.de systemd[1]: lighttpd.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Mar 15 02:19:11 km15501.servernode.de systemd[1]: Unit lighttpd.service entered failed state.
Mar 15 02:19:11 km15501.servernode.de systemd[1]: lighttpd.service failed.
[root@km15501 lighttpd]
```

anyone has any idea with this kind of problem? i tried to change the port from 81 to 8080 and 8081 nothing worked.

**UPDATE:**

i run:

```
/usr/local/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

result:

```
Aborted
```

i run:

```
 strace  /usr/local/sbin/lighttpd -D -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf
```

result:

```
execve("/usr/local/sbin/lighttpd", ["/usr/local/sbin/lighttpd", "-D", "-f", "/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf"], [/* 23 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xd3f000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc2670c000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=63292, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 63292, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc266fc000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpcre.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=398272, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2490888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc2628b000
mprotect(0x7fbc262eb000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc264ea000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5f000) = 0x7fbc264ea000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19520, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc26087000
mprotect(0x7fbc2608a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc26289000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fbc26289000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\6\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=6928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc266fb000
mmap(NULL, 2101312, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc25e85000
mprotect(0x7fbc25e86000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc26085000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc26085000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\246\1\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1287944, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3368432, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc25b4e000
mprotect(0x7fbc25c83000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc25e82000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x134000) = 0x7fbc25e82000
mmap(0x7fbc25e84000, 1520, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc25e84000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\"\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=44096, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2128952, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc25946000
mprotect(0x7fbc2594d000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc25b4c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7fbc25b4c000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240l\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=142304, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc266fa000
mmap(NULL, 2208864, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc2572a000
mprotect(0x7fbc25740000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc25940000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7fbc25940000
mmap(0x7fbc25942000, 13408, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc25942000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2107816, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3932736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc25369000
mprotect(0x7fbc2551f000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc2571f000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b6000) = 0x7fbc2571f000
mmap(0x7fbc25725000, 16960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc25725000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc266f9000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc266f7000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fbc266f7740) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc2571f000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc25940000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc25b4c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc25e82000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc26085000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc26289000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc264ea000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x637000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc2670d000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fbc266fc000, 63292)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7fbc266f7a10)         = 16832
set_robust_list(0x7fbc266f7a20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7fbc25730780, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7fbc25730810, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xd3f000
brk(0xd60000)                           = 0xd60000
brk(0)                                  = 0xd60000
getuid()                                = 0
getcwd("/etc/lighttpd", 1087)           = 14
stat("/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6396, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf", O_RDONLY) = 3
mmap(NULL, 6396, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc2670a000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7fbc2670a000, 6396)            = 0
open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY)             = 3
close(0)                                = 0
dup2(3, 0)                              = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY)             = 3
close(1)                                = 0
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/var/www/vhosts/youdive.eu/httpdocs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/var/www/vhosts/youdive.eu/httpdocs", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/VAR/WWW/VHOSTS/YOUDIVE.EU/HTTPDOCS", 0x7fff464fee70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
futex(0x7fbc2628a0d0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_indexfile.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=40885, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2105560, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc25166000
mprotect(0x7fbc25168000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc25367000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7fbc25367000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc25367000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_access.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\v\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=40348, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2105488, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24f63000
mprotect(0x7fbc24f65000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc25164000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7fbc25164000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc25164000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_simple_vhost.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\r\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=41645, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2105536, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24d60000
mprotect(0x7fbc24d62000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24f61000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7fbc24f61000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24f61000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_secdownload.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=46386, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109672, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24b5c000
mprotect(0x7fbc24b5f000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24d5e000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fbc24d5e000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24d5e000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_flv_streaming.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000\20\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=48258, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109704, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24958000
mprotect(0x7fbc2495a000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24b5a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fbc24b5a000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24b5a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_h264_streaming.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0`\32\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=334898, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2167496, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24746000
mprotect(0x7fbc24757000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24956000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10000) = 0x7fbc24956000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24956000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_accesslog.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\24\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=59433, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2113904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24541000
mprotect(0x7fbc24545000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24744000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x3000) = 0x7fbc24744000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24744000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_dirlisting.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\31\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=73805, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2118376, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc2433b000
mprotect(0x7fbc24340000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc2453f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x4000) = 0x7fbc2453f000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc2453f000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_staticfile.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \24\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=52229, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109792, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc24137000
mprotect(0x7fbc2413a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24339000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fbc24339000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24339000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/usr/local/lib/mod_chunked.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\17\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=46895, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109672, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fbc23f33000
mprotect(0x7fbc23f35000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fbc24135000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7fbc24135000
close(3)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7fbc24135000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
open("/var/run/lighttpd.pid", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_TRUNC, 0644) = -1 EEXIST (File exists)
stat("/var/run/lighttpd.pid", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6, ...}) = 0
open("/var/run/lighttpd.pid", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644) = 3
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=4*1024}) = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 4
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8080), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(4, 1024)                         = 0
getgid()                                = 0
getuid()                                = 0
write(3, "16832\n", 6)                  = 6
close(3)                                = 0
open("/var/log/lighttpd/access.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0644) = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
open("/var/log/lighttpd/error.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0644) = 5
fcntl(5, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
write(5, "log.c.142: (trace) server starte"..., 35) = 35
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY)             = 6
close(2)                                = 0
dup2(6, 2)                              = 2
close(6)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x409c00, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x409c00, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {0x409c00, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x409c00, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x409c00, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {0x409c00, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7fbc25739100}, NULL, 8) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0xd60000
brk(0xd83000)                           = 0xd83000
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc23732000
mprotect(0x7fbc23732000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fbc23f31fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fbc23f329d0, tls=0x7fbc23f32700, child_tidptr=0x7fbc23f329d0) = 16833
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc22f31000
mprotect(0x7fbc22f31000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fbc23730fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fbc237319d0, tls=0x7fbc23731700, child_tidptr=0x7fbc237319d0) = 16834
futex(0x7fbc25e84488, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)    = 1
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc22730000
mprotect(0x7fbc22730000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fbc22f2ffb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fbc22f309d0, tls=0x7fbc22f30700, child_tidptr=0x7fbc22f309d0) = 16835
futex(0x7fbc25e84488, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)    = 1
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc21f2f000
mprotect(0x7fbc21f2f000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fbc2272efb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fbc2272f9d0, tls=0x7fbc2272f700, child_tidptr=0x7fbc2272f9d0) = 16836
futex(0x7fbc25e84488, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)    = 1
mmap(NULL, 69632, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7fbc266e6000
mprotect(0x7fbc266e6000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7fbc266f5fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7fbc266f69d0, tls=0x7fbc266f6700, child_tidptr=0x7fbc266f69d0) = 16837
futex(0x7fbc25e84488, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)    = 1
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
write(2, "Attempt to unlock mutex that was"..., 44) = 44
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
tgkill(16832, 16832, SIGABRT)           = 0
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=16832, si_uid=0} ---
+++ killed by SIGABRT +++
Aborted
```

the lighttpd.conf is here:
http://pastebin.com/jRYSef2W

Comment: Assuming I'm reading that correctly something sent it an ABRT signal. Does that exact status/error/output repeat itself every time you start it? Or do other things happen also?

Comment: @EtanReisner yes each time i try to run service lighttpd start i will get above log, not sure what is killing it.

Comment: Run the lighttpd command by hand and see what you get?

Comment: added extra info.. please refresh the question

Comment: That "Attempt to unlock mutex that was" message looks interesting. Searching for that online shows a number of people having that with various pieces of software. Upgrading gtk/glib seems to help a number of them.

Comment: glib version is
libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1 -> libglibmm_generate_extra_defs-2.4.so.1.3.0
libglibmm-2.4.so.1 -> libglibmm-2.4.so.1.3.0
libglib-2.0.so.0 -> libglib-2.0.so.0.4200.2
libdbus-glib-1.so.2 -> libdbus-glib-1.so.2.2.2

Comment: What are the package versions for gtk+, gdk and glib (though I think this is a gtk/gdk issue if it is the one I'm seeing people mention online). Are there updated packages available? Did you build any of this software yourself?

Comment: lighttpd are compiled from source

Comment: On CentOS 7? Against the current package versions? Does recompiling help?

Comment: the default package do not come with mod x264 and mod sec download, we have to compile the src and install it to /usr/local/sbin/ the default will goes to /usr/sbin/

Comment: You can almost certainly compile just the modules you need and not the whole thing but that's neither here nor there. What version of lighttpd? Did you compile anything else to get lighttpd building?

Comment: well the compilation are success with no error on the first place.. im using lighttpd-1.5.0_mod_h264_streaming-2.2.9.tar.gz and no other tools are compiled for this installation, but before that i did run this: yum install pcre-devel glib2-devel lighttpd -y i have no problem with these step and file with centos 6 for years, and also some centos 7.. just this one of the machine give me the issue of "Attempt to unlock mutex that was"

Comment: googled the "Attempt to unlock mutex that was" some of it to do with system kernel as well..